# async exception occured when silverlight access wcf service hosted in iis 7

Tags: wcf, silverlight, asynchronous, invalidation

folks, I encountered a strange problem when I created SL client for accessing WCF service hosted in IIS7. My service contract is shown as below:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAuthorizationService
{
    [OperationContract]
    RoleMetadata GetRoleMetadata();

    [OperationContract]
    void CreateNewRole(Guid id, string name, string description);
    [OperationContract]
    void UpdateRole(Guid id, string name, string description);
    [OperationContract]
    void RemoveRole(Guid id);

    [OperationContract]
    void AddPersonsToRole(Guid roleID, IEnumerable<int> pids);
    [OperationContract]
    void RemovePersonsFromRole(Guid roleID, IEnumerable<int> pids);

    [OperationContract]
    void GrantRolePermissions(Guid roleID, Int64 mask);
    [OperationContract]
    void RevokeRolePermissions(Guid roleID, Int64 mask);
}
```

I said the problem is strange because that parts of methods of this service can be accessed and the others are not accessible. the condition is, when I tried to access method GetRoleMetadata, I got an error which showed an async exception occured and the result was invalid. But when I called CreateNewRole I got smoothly new record in database.

I have checked both service and client configuration many times and rewrote service in some different implementations and I reaped a useless crop. So I hope there could be masters who can help me to defeat it.

One more thing, It runs under developing environment perfectly (vs2013, sqlexpress 2008). The problem arises after implementing project on the server(Windows Server2008 R2 enterprise, SQLServer 2008 enterprise, IIS7, .net framework 4.0).

[2014-10-16] I rewrote service and corresponding client code with WCF channel mode. the newly contracts like this:

```
 [ServiceContract]
public interface IAuthority
{
    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginGetRoles(AsyncCallback callback, object state);
    RoleMetaData EndGetRoles(IAsyncResult result);
    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginUpdateRole(bool addNewRole, Guid id, string name, string description, AsyncCallback callback, object state);
    void EndUpdateRole(IAsyncResult result);
    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginRemoveRole(Guid id, AsyncCallback callback, object state);
    void EndRemoveRole(IAsyncResult result);
    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginAlterRoleMembers(Guid roleID, bool addMembers, IEnumerable<int> pids, AsyncCallback callback, object state);
    void EndAlterRoleMembers(IAsyncResult result);
    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginAlterRolePermissions(Guid roleID, bool grantPermissions, Int64 mask, AsyncCallback callback, object state);
    void EndAlterRolePermissions(IAsyncResult result);
}
```

and then at client side I use ChannelFactory and Channel to access service. However, the problem still remains. I can access all methods but GetRoles. This time I got a new error message as this: "[HttpWebRequest_WebException_RemoteServer] NotFound". My heart is being broken. The next step, I am about to rewrite the whole UI and service proxy, namely, a completely new client to test this problem. God bless me.

[2014-10-16 23:32 Chengdu]
I have wrote a newly simple client to access service. The problem is still there. However that makes it clear that something at server is wrong. Tomorrow I must carefully check things at server side. IIS configuration is the No.1 suspect? But there are yet 5 services which share the same configurations with this unfortunate authorization service and run as expected.

WCF trace also didn't show me due respect! I have configured trace in web.config as follow and just got an empty file.

```
<system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel"  switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"    propagateActivity="true" >
                <listeners>
                    <add name="xml" />
                </listeners>
            </source>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="xml" />
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
        <sharedListeners>
            <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="D:\trace.xml"/>
        </sharedListeners>
    </system.diagnostics>
<system.serviceModel>
        <diagnostics>
            <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true"
                                        logMalformedMessages="true"
                                        logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
                                        logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
                                        maxMessagesToLog="500"/>
        </diagnostics>
<!--...-->
</system.serviceModel>
```

Masters, please show me an epiphany and bail out me!

Answer (score 1):

Oh yeah! I fixed it! I am given a big lesson and should sum all up. My steps:

1.Carefully read specifications about WCF tracing.( http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36031/WCF-Tracing-FAQs, there are also articles about detailed configuring trace in MSDN which can be easily found out) And I think the best practice is to configure tracing using Service Configure Editing Tool instead of hand editing, thus can avoid configuration errors which could cause failed tracing.

2.After I correctly configured wcf tracing, I got activity error log with red foreground in service trace log viewer. After checking it I quickly located the error and corrected it.

3.My exception is from data access layer(DAL). A colleague unintentional modified a store procedure - just swapped the positions of two columns of same data type. He was unware of it and didn't notify me. That took place only at implementation server not in developing environment. So I didn't generate new DAL classes from implementing server database. So logical error always occurred at my service.It shows that the Entity Framework is probably a good choice which can avoid similar problems.

4.Another inside lesson is that the management of our ad hoc team for this project is too loose. The cooperation can be counted as failed in some degree because of such a big communication matter.